# How to add 'i=' tag in DKIM signature (opendkim)

Tags: dkim, opendkim

I would like to add the `i`, Identity — the identity of the signer  — in email address format

Can you help me?

`/etc/opendkim.conf` contains:

```
KeyTable                refile:/var/lib/dkimkeys/keyTable
SigningTable            refile:/var/lib/dkimkeys/signingTable
OversignHeaders         From
```

`/var/lib/dkimkeys/signingTable` contains:

```
*.mydomain.com selector._domainkey.mydomain.com
```

I would like to add `i=` tag in email siganture.

What actions should I take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it is possible to do this by adding a second field to your `SigningTable` entry.

```
sub.mydomain.com    selector._domainkey.mydomain.com:%
*.mydomain.com      selector._domainkey.mydomain.com:i-tag-value
```

Either one of those will work. The `%` will be replaced by the sender's domain in the `From:` header.